# Semantic or logical error?

Tags: semantics

I've seen a lot of questions on this subject, but I still haven't been able to figure out if the following is a semantic or logical error.
Say I have the following Java code:

```
boolean a = false;
if (a = false) System.out.println("yes");
else System.out.println("no");
```

You may already see I probably wanted to write down `==` instead of `=`, but: the program compiles just fine and runs without errors. It does, however, not give me the intended result.

I found somewhere that semantic errors always give an error (at compile- or runtime), so then this must be a logical error. However, another text said semantic errors not always give an error. Thus question is: does the above example contain a semantic or logical error?

Comment: Aren't these two the same things? Every where I read about these terms it seems the definition of both is that the program is syntactically valid (ie. it is a valid program), but it does not do what the programmer intended.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen I first thought the same thing, but that's actually not the case. Also, for example, this would be considered a semantic error if `a` were a `String`.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen (As far as I understand, this is because the _pattern_ is correct, the circumstances (variable type) are not, though.)

Answer (score -1):

By writing the following expression: `a = false` you are basically assigning a variable with value false which works fine and return true as succeeded operation and that is why you will always print "yes" in the console.

Comment: Not only did you not answer his question, your interpretation of what `if (a = false)` does is also wrong. The result is not `true` because the assignment was successful, it is `false` because the value of an assignment expression in java is the value assigned, so it is `false`.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen is right, I knew that. Could you read the question another time, but more carefully?